# UbuntuをCUIで起動したい

Tags: linux, ubuntu

VirtualBox上にUbuntuをインストールしたのですが、CUIで最初から起動する方法はありますか?
現在の状態だと、起動すると必ずGUIが表示されてしまいます。
これを最初からCUIで起動するようにしてsshで外部からログインしたいのですが、どうすればよいのでしょうか?

[ubuntuをCUIで起動する | nqou.net](https://www.nqou.net/2014/03/19/080944/)

上記のページのように`/etc/default/grub`を編集後に`sudo update-grub`を実行しましたが、その後で再起動してもGUIで起動してしまいます。

環境:
VirtualBox 5.2.22
Host OS: Windows10 Home 1803
Guest OS: Ubuntu 18.10

Comment: リンク先の手順をそのまま実行した場合でも、あなたが実際に行った操作を質問文にも含めるようにしてください (今回の場合なら`/etc/default/grub`をどのように編集したのか)。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

こちらのページに書かれているように、systemctl のデフォルトのランレベルを `graphical.target` (5) から `multi-user.target` (3) に変更するのはいかがでしょう。

- [Ubuntu 16.04 LTS のランレベルを変更して CUI で動かす](https://blog.amedama.jp/entry/2017/06/07/221816)

Comment: ろはんさん、回答ありがとうございます！　もし可能であれば、リンク先の内容の簡単なまとめを回答に含むようにしてみてください。スタック・オーバーフローでは Q&A が長期的に役に立つようにしようとしており、リンクだけの回答だとリンク切れした後に価値が無くなってしまうからです。回答下部の「編集」から自由に追記できますので、お手数ですがどうぞよろしくお願いいたします <(_ _)>

Comment: ろはん さん、私の方で簡単に要約して編集してみました。変なところがあれば適宜直していただければと思います :)

Answer (score 1):

text オプションは効かないので、次のようにしてください。

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="systemd.unit=multi-user.target nosplash"
```

または

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="systemd.unit=multi-user.target quiet nosplash"
```